# How to use population data in custom activity for Journey builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We are creating a custom Journey builder activity that needs to send additional data using the inArguments variables in the execute section. In the [How Data Binding Works](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm) it is described that you can use data bindings in a journey Builder Custom Activity. We have demographic data linked to the contact using a Population in Contact Builder, but I do not see anywhere how to fetch additional contact data from the population data.

The population is called "Individual" and one piece of data that we need from the linked data extension is called "AdressRow".

How would I write that for an inArguments to work?

We have tried:

```
   "arguments": {
   "execute": {
       "inArguments": [
        {
          "Adress": "{{Contact.Attribute.Individual.AdressRow}}"
        },
```

But that did not return anything.