# Custom Activity use popoplation

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have created a custom activity. It is working fine now (thanks to this forum). I am adding inArguments by {{Contact.Attribute.DENAME.FIELD}} and the contact get injected to Journey.

Now I want to use the contacts in the data extension which I am using as Population.

I tried few ways which mention in Data binding document but still cannot get data data from population.

I am sure many people have used this and can help in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is actually interesting. I'm just "subscribing" to this tread, wasn't aware that the DE changed on a systemic level.

Comment: there is a question from march that asks the same, without an answer though https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163209/how-to-use-population-data-in-custom-activity-for-journey-builder